# Everyplay broken with Unity3D 4.1 - "iPhone_GlesSupport.h" missing

Tags: ios, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, everyplay

It seems like Unity3D 4.1 isn't including some of the files it used to in the iOS builds.  Everyplay is creating compile errors because "iPhone_GlesSupport.h" can't be found.  Looks like this was a standard file in Unity's XCode projects before 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it was a standard file in Unity 3.5 and 4.0 series.

4.1 release brought some major changes to graphics pipeline and we'll
be releasing an update to the SDK and Unity plugin ASAP.

Comment: SDK 1.0.13 now supports Unity 3.5, 4.0 and 4.1.